# Why is <Target Name="Build"> not found in any .csproj file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

Just curious - whenever I see xml of .csproj , it starts with `DefaultTargets="Build"` and hence I assume that `<Target Name="Build">` should be present; However, I have never found this default target in any `.csproj` file.

Does VS inject this target before compilation or does msbuild built it by default. What happens internally?

Comment: see the buildfiles that are imported by means of <import ...>

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Near the bottom of the file you'll see this; `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` which imports the standard targets, "Build" is one of these. The import generates the "Build" target in a dynamic fashion based on the other data available in the your project file.

Comment: How can I follow the $(MSBuildToolsPath) / $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) paths to see what the actual targets are?

Answer (score 6):

A csproj typically has this:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

which according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164312.aspx) also imports Microsoft.Common.targets which is where that target is defined.

Answer (score 1):

There is one or more < Import ...> somewhere in the project file that imports other file(s) that should have that target...